# XPath-3 CSV generation

Tags: xml, csv, xpath, xidel

I'm trying to convert the following XML to CSV using XPath 3.0 (`xidel --xpath`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<csv>
    <record>
        <field1>A</field1>
        <field2>B</field2>
        <field3>C</field3>
    </record>
    <record>
        <field2> </field2>
        <field3></field3>
    </record>
    <record>
        <field1>,,</field1>
        <field2>""</field2>
        <field3>..</field3>
        <field3>.
                 .</field3>
    </record>
</csv>
```

My expected output would be:

```
field1,field2,field3
A,B,C
, ,""
",,","""""",".
                 ."
```

I've got a few problems (the first one isn't specific to `xidel`):

1. <s>I get the fields names with `distinct-values(/csv/record/*/name())`; how can I use that sequence for extracting the data in the records?</s>
2. I would like to differentiate between a *missing* and an *empty* field but the `text()` selector of `xidel` doesn't seem to care about that; is it a XPath feature or a `xidel` bug?
3. <s>I can't make `return` work; does `xidel` use a different syntax?</s>

###### Update

I solved #1 myself and #3 was resolved by @ConalTuohy in his comment.

Here's what I got now:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
IFS='' read -r -d '' xpath <<'EOF'

let $csv-escape-string := function($str as xs:string) as xs:string {
    if ( matches( $str, ',|"|\n' ) )
    then
        concat('"',replace($str,'"','""'),'"')
    else
        $str
},
$fields-names := distinct-values(/csv/record/*/name()),
$csv := (
    string-join( $fields-names, ',' ),
    /csv/record/string-join(
        (
            for $fn in $fields-names
            return $csv-escape-string(string( *[name()=$fn][last()]/text() ))
        ), ','
    )
)
return $csv

EOF
xidel --xpath "$xpath" file.xml
```

But the output isn't what I would like it to be:

```
field1,field2,field3
A,B,C
,,
",,","""""",".
                 ."
```

Could someone try it with an other XPath-3 processor for making sure that it is `xidel` that is normalizing `text()`?

Comment: I don't know xidel, but your XPath expression should start with the `let` keyword to make those variable assignments, and end with a `return` statement.

Comment: @ConalTuohy I updated my code; do you have an XPath-3 processor at hand for trying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**<sub>I've made "better" alternatives afterwards.</sub>**

The main improvement is that now the selector `/csv/record` only needs to be specified once.

---

1. Outputting quoted fields only:

```bash
let
$records := /csv/record,
$fields := distinct-values( $records/*/local-name() )

return (
    string-join( $fields, "," ),
    for $r in $records return
    string-join(
        for $f in $fields return
        """" || replace($r/*[local-name()=$f][last()],"""","""""") || """",
        ","
    )
)
```

```
field1,field2,field3
"A","B","C"
""," ",""
",,","""""",".
                 ."
```

---

2. Differentiating between `null` and `empty` values, and quoting fields only when required:

```bash
let $csv-escape-string := function($str as xs:string?) as xs:string {
    if ( not(exists($str)) ) then
        ""
    else if ( $str = "" ) then
        """"""
    else if ( matches( $str, ",|""""|\n" ) ) then
        """" || replace($str,"""","""""") || """"
    else
        $str
},
$records := /csv/record,
$fields := distinct-values( $records/*/local-name() )

return (
    string-join( $fields, "," ),
    for $r in $records return
    string-join(
        for $f in $fields return
        $csv-escape-string($r/*[local-name()=$f][last()]),
        ","
    )
)
```

```
field1,field2,field3
A,B,C
, ,""
",,","""""",".
                 ."
```

Answer (score 2):

> *But the output isn't what I would like it to be*

Most likely your `xidel` binary is too old.

> *`xidel --xpath "$xpath" file.xml`*

The reason you put the query in `$xpath` is because of the single- and double-quotes, I guess? It sure is a nifty way to circumvent this problem, but not needed if you use double-quotes for strings. `--xpath "function('string')"` is for [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), while `--xpath 'function("string")'` is for [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). To escape a double-quote within a string simply enter a second one:

```
$ xidel -s input.xml -e '
  let $field-names:=distinct-values(csv/record/*/name()) return (
    join($field-names,","),
    csv/record/join(
      for $fn in $field-names return
      string(*[name()=$fn][last()]) ! (
        if (matches(.,",|""|\n"))
        then concat("""",replace(.,"""",""""""),"""")
        else .
      ),","
    )
  )
'
```

Alternatively you can use the XQuery notation:

```
if (matches(.,",|&quot;|\n"))
then concat("&quot;",replace(.,"&quot;","&quot;&quot;"),"&quot;")
else .
```

You can also use `xidel`'s own "extended string"-syntax (and use another let-variable instead of `!`):

```
$ xidel -s input.xml -e '
  let $field-names:=distinct-values(csv/record/*/name()) return (
    join($field-names,","),
    csv/record/join(
      for $fn in $field-names
      let $val:=string(*[name()=$fn][last()])
      return
      if (matches($val,",|""|\n"))
      then x"""{replace($val,"""","""""")}"""
      else $val,
      ","
    )
  )
'
```

Comment: I tested `Xidel 0.9.8` on Linux and it still strips the leading and trailing spaces :-(

Comment: @Fravadona v0.9.8 is not the latest version. http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html#downloads: _"It is recommended to use the 0.9.9 version"_.

Comment: The pre-built binaries of v0.9.9 for macOS crash with this example. Same problem after compiling `xidel` with `fpc` 3.2.X; I had to downgrade `fpc` to version 3.0.4a for `xidel` to work on macOS.

Comment: @Fravadona In that case I think you'd better officially [report](https://github.com/benibela/xidel/issues) this, because I'm not a macOS-user myself (and neither is Benito, `xidel`'s author).

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/benibela/xidel/issues/93

Answer (score 1):

When I ran your code on [XML Workbench](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/) I got the following result:

```
A,B,C
, ,
",,","""""",".
                 ."
```

NB I changed the last line of the query to `return string-join($csv, codepoints-to-string(10))` to return the entire CSV as a single string, so XML Workbench didn't quote each string in the result sequence individually, as it otherwise would.

Comment: Tank you for pointing that out. The output is valid (the space in the second line isn't stripped) so there's indeed a problem `xidel`. I got it working as intended with XML_Workbench so now I'm going to look for an other XPath-3 processor (and report the bug to `xidel`)

Comment: Good luck! XML Workbench is based on SaxonJS from Saxonica, who offer XSLT 3 processors for other platforms, too. https://www.saxonica.com/products/products.xml